# how to stop color overlap (bleeding) when filling second time with magic wand select in Adobe Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, fill

When using the magic wand to select an area to fill (first image), when I fill the first time, there is no color overlap on the edges  (second image). But if I fill the same area again with a different color after having filled it once there is a color overlap (third image). It's very subtle but you can see that the black part gets partially dyed purple. Is there a way to stop this color bleeding effect when filling a second time? I'm hoping to try different colors when coloring an image but this kind of makes it difficult. Note: This only occurs if I deselect the area and select it second time to fill with another color

[image: this area was white before but I filled it in with a light tan color]

[image: after filling first time there is no bleeding on the edges]

[image: after filling again with another color there is bleeding]

Answer (score 1):

The Magic Wand can be a pretty terrible selection tool and other methods can typically be better.

However, with the **Magic Wand** tool selected, adjust the options in the **Control Bar** across the top of the screen.

[image]

- Reduce the value of `Tolerance`
- Reduce the `Sample size`
- Untick `Anti-Alias`

All of these can result in more defined edges when using the tool.

Answer (score 0):

Magic wand makes the same results in the 2nd time only if the colors are the same as in the 1st time. If you have painted something to the selected area so that the color at the edge has changed at least the anti-aliasing zone will be different.

Workarounds:

1. Save the selection with a name before using it. Then you can call it back.
2. Make the experiments to a new empty layer. The selection made in the original layer work also in other layers. If it went wrong you simply delete the bad layer and insert a new one.
3. create a layer mask to an empty layer - it adapts to the selection automatically if you have one active. Then you can fill the layer as many times with new color as you want.

You can also convert the layer mask to a selection if you need just a selection.

Answer (score 0):

- `Ctrl/Cmd + Click` on the Layer thumbnail is better to select back a layer, than using magic wand on it, either if it's flat color.
- You can also lock the transparent pixel of the layer with this button on layer panel
  [image: Layer panel lock transparent]

  and then fill it with color.